# Django TastyPie ForeignKey full = true not working

Tags: django, tastypie

I have two model Product and CartItem :

```
#product models.py
class Product(models.Model):
   objects = ProductManger()
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   description = models.TextField()

#CartItem models.py
class CartItem(models.Model):
   objects = CartItemManager()
   cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart)
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
   quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
```

I want to get all cartitems for a cart, for that in api.py (tastypie) i have the following:

```
class CartItemRelatedResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
       queryset = Product.objects.all()
       resource_name = 'item_product'
       allowed_methods = ['get'] 
       include_resource_uri = False       
       authentication = SessionAuthentication()

class CartItemResource(ModelResource):
     product = fields.ForeignKey(CartItemRelatedResource, 'product', full=True)

    class Meta:
       queryset = CartItem.objects.all()
       resource_name = 'cart_item'
       excludes = ['modification_date']
       allowed_methods = ['post', 'get', 'delete']
       authentication = SessionAuthentication()

    def get_cart_items(self, request, **kwargs):
       self.method_check(request, allowed=['get'])
       self.is_authenticated(request)
       cart_id = request.GET.get('id', '')
       items = CartItem.objects.filter(cart__exact = cart_id)
       data = serializers.serialize('json', items)
       return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

But when i get_cart_items, the response has the pk of the product, it doesn't have the product name or description. I want to get the product name too in the response. From what i have read full=true is the best solution(with minimum requests because a cart can have multiple cart items).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of get_cart_items() is not using the Tastypie code to fetch, that's why full=True is not working.

`full=True` will work if you use the Tastypie default handlers to get the data.  You don't need to write your own get_cart_items().

Comment: thanks fro your reply. Should i be using `def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):   cart_id= request.GET.get('cart_id') ... `

Comment: I don't full understand what you're trying to do, but in the general case you don't need to write any code at all, just use the default tastypie url.

Comment: I would like to have the url like /api/cart_item/cart/?id=1 opposed to /api/cart_item/cart/?cart__id=id. I will try with the later one and if it works will accepted your answer. Thanks for your help. I am new to django-tastypie :)

Comment: Oh, I get it now.  It would have helped if you added that in your answer.  It's probably best to over-ride the check_filters() and build_filters() functions to allow your filter.